# Multi line string does not parse

Tags: yaml

I don't understand why the first YAML multi line string parses, but
the second one embedded as a value does not parse:

```
ignore_newlines: >
            this is really a
            single line of text
            despite appearances

xmas: {   
   day: "Dec 25",
   another_ignore_newlines: >
            this is really a
            single line of text
            despite appearances
   cleanup: "Dec 26"
}
```

This may be just another "oddness" of YAML, but why.....?

Answer (score 2):

[In YAML it is not allowed to have block style nodes nested within flow style](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2799181). And your value for `xmas` is a  flow style mapping, which contains a (folding literal) block style scalar value for `another_ignore_newlines`.
This would not work as there should also be a trailing `,` on the line before `cleanup`.

Try removing the `{` and `}` and probably also the trailing comma after `"Dec 25"`:

```
ignore_newlines: >
            this is really a
            single line of text
            despite appearances

xmas:
   day: "Dec 25"
   another_ignore_newlines: >
            this is really a
            single line of text
            despite appearances
   cleanup: "Dec 26"
```